# How do I scale an axis for time intervals using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I want to plot a histogram of a bunch of time intervals:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Generate 1000 random time difftime values
set.seed(919)
center <- as.POSIXct(as.Date("2014-12-18"))
df <- data.frame(
    center, 
    noise = center + rnorm(1000, mean = 86400, sd = 86400 * 3)
    ) %>%
  mutate(diff = center - noise)

# Plot histogram of the difftime values -- 
# coerce to numeric, because otherwise it won't plot
qplot(data = df, x = as.numeric(diff), geom = "histogram")
```

I get this plot:

[image: histogram]

Is there a way to change the x-axis to be reasonable date-time values?  (That is, I'd want 86400 to be labelled as "1 day", -86400 to be labelled as "- 1 day", etc.)  I could do this manually by setting breaks and labels, but I'm hoping that ggplot has a way to handle difftime values automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of subtracting the dates you can use `difftime()` and use `days` as the units.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Generate 1000 random time difftime values
set.seed(919)
center <- as.POSIXct(as.Date("2014-12-18"))
df <- data.frame(
    center, 
    noise = center + rnorm(1000, mean = 86400, sd = 86400 * 3)
    ) %>%
  mutate(diff = difftime(center, noise, unit = "days"))

# Plot histogram of the difftime values -- 
# coerce to numeric, because otherwise it won't plot
qplot(data = df, x = as.numeric(diff), geom = "histogram") +
  xlab("Days") + ylab("Count")
```

[image]